# AME package not finding template under CONDA environment

Tags: python, conda, bioinformatics

I'm using AME software from the MEME-Suite package under Conda (4.5.4) on a SLURM server.
When using AME, I receive the following error message:

```
Bad file name.  
Bad file name.  
Bad file name.  
Bad file name.  
Bad file name.  
Bad file name.  
Bad file name.  
Bad file name.  
Bad file name.  
Bad file name.  
Bad file name.  
Bad file name.  
FATAL: Template does not contain data section.
```

It looks like AME is not able to retrieve its template file for the output production
I tried the following solutions:

- `conda install meme=5.0.2`
- `conda install meme=5.3.0`
- `conda install -c bioconda/label/cf201901 meme`
- solutions proposed here: https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/issues/22909 and here: https://www.biostars.org/p/401084/

Unfortunately nothing solved my problem.
I have to maintain Python 3.X version and so cannot use the MEME version for Python 2.X.

**Any idea how to install MEME in this context?**

Here are the dependencies from the Conda environment:

```yaml
dependencies:
  - bioconductor-seqlogo=1.56.0=r40_0
  - blast=2.10.1=pl526he19e7b1_3
  - clustalo=1.2.4=he1b5a44_3
  - entrez-direct=13.9=pl526h375a9b1_1
  - logomaker=0.8=pyh864c0ab_1
  - meme=5.3.0=py37pl526h072abfd_0
  - perl-app-cpanminus=1.7044=pl526_1
  - perl-archive-tar=2.32=pl526_0
  - perl-base=2.23=pl526_1
  - perl-business-isbn=3.004=pl526_0
  - perl-business-isbn-data=20140910.003=pl526_0
  - perl-carp=1.38=pl526_3
  - perl-cgi=4.44=pl526h14c3975_1
  - perl-common-sense=3.74=pl526_2
  - perl-compress-raw-bzip2=2.087=pl526he1b5a44_0
  - perl-compress-raw-zlib=2.087=pl526hc9558a2_0
  - perl-constant=1.33=pl526_1
  - perl-data-dumper=2.173=pl526_0
  - perl-dbi=1.642=pl526_0
  - perl-digest-hmac=1.03=pl526_3
  - perl-digest-md5=2.55=pl526_0
  - perl-encode=2.88=pl526_1
  - perl-encode-locale=1.05=pl526_6
  - perl-exporter=5.72=pl526_1
  - perl-exporter-tiny=1.002001=pl526_0
  - perl-extutils-makemaker=7.36=pl526_1
  - perl-file-listing=6.04=pl526_1
  - perl-file-path=2.16=pl526_0
  - perl-file-temp=0.2304=pl526_2
  - perl-file-which=1.23=pl526_0
  - perl-html-parser=3.72=pl526h6bb024c_5
  - perl-html-tagset=3.20=pl526_3
  - perl-html-template=2.97=pl526_1
  - perl-html-tree=5.07=pl526_1
  - perl-http-cookies=6.04=pl526_0
  - perl-http-daemon=6.01=pl526_1
  - perl-http-date=6.02=pl526_3
  - perl-http-message=6.18=pl526_0
  - perl-http-negotiate=6.01=pl526_3
  - perl-io-compress=2.087=pl526he1b5a44_0
  - perl-io-html=1.001=pl526_2
  - perl-io-socket-ssl=2.066=pl526_0
  - perl-io-zlib=1.10=pl526_2
  - perl-json=4.02=pl526_0
  - perl-json-xs=2.34=pl526h6bb024c_3
  - perl-libwww-perl=6.39=pl526_0
  - perl-list-moreutils=0.428=pl526_1
  - perl-list-moreutils-xs=0.428=pl526_0
  - perl-log-log4perl=1.49=pl526_0
  - perl-lwp-mediatypes=6.04=pl526_0
  - perl-lwp-protocol-https=6.07=pl526_4
  - perl-math-cdf=0.1=pl526h14c3975_5
  - perl-mime-base64=3.15=pl526_1
  - perl-mozilla-ca=20180117=pl526_1
  - perl-net-http=6.19=pl526_0
  - perl-net-ssleay=1.88=pl526h90d6eec_0
  - perl-ntlm=1.09=pl526_4
  - perl-parent=0.236=pl526_1
  - perl-pathtools=3.75=pl526h14c3975_1
  - perl-scalar-list-utils=1.52=pl526h516909a_0
  - perl-socket=2.027=pl526_1
  - perl-storable=3.15=pl526h14c3975_0
  - perl-test-requiresinternet=0.05=pl526_0
  - perl-time-local=1.28=pl526_1
  - perl-try-tiny=0.30=pl526_1
  - perl-types-serialiser=1.0=pl526_2
  - perl-uri=1.76=pl526_0
  - perl-www-robotrules=6.02=pl526_3
  - perl-xml-namespacesupport=1.12=pl526_0
  - perl-xml-sax=1.02=pl526_0
  - perl-xml-sax-base=1.09=pl526_0
  - perl-xml-sax-expat=0.51=pl526_3
  - perl-xml-simple=2.25=pl526_1
  - perl-xsloader=0.24=pl526_0
  - perl-yaml=1.29=pl526_0
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=1_gnu
  - _r-mutex=1.0.1=anacondar_1
  - argtable2=2.13=h14c3975_1001
  - binutils_impl_linux-64=2.35.1=h193b22a_2
  - binutils_linux-64=2.35=h67ddf6f_30
  - biopython=1.78=py37h5e8e339_1
  - bwidget=1.9.14=ha770c72_0
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h7f98852_4
  - c-ares=1.17.1=h36c2ea0_0
  - ca-certificates=2020.12.5=ha878542_0
  - cairo=1.16.0=hcf35c78_1003
  - certifi=2020.12.5=py37h89c1867_1
  - curl=7.71.1=he644dc0_8
  - cycler=0.10.0=py_2
  - dbus=1.13.6=he372182_0
  - expat=2.2.10=h9c3ff4c_0
  - fontconfig=2.13.1=hba837de_1004
  - freetype=2.10.4=h0708190_1
  - fribidi=1.0.10=h36c2ea0_0
  - gcc_impl_linux-64=7.5.0=hda68d29_13
  - gcc_linux-64=7.5.0=h47867f9_30
  - gettext=0.19.8.1=hf34092f_1004
  - gfortran_impl_linux-64=7.5.0=h56cb351_18
  - gfortran_linux-64=7.5.0=h78c8a43_30
  - ghostscript=9.53.3=h58526e2_2
  - glib=2.66.1=h680cd38_0
  - graphite2=1.3.13=h58526e2_1001
  - gsl=2.6=he838d99_2
  - gst-plugins-base=1.14.5=h0935bb2_2
  - gstreamer=1.14.5=h36ae1b5_2
  - gxx_impl_linux-64=7.5.0=h64c220c_13
  - gxx_linux-64=7.5.0=h555fc39_30
  - harfbuzz=2.4.0=h9f30f68_3
  - icu=64.2=he1b5a44_1
  - jpeg=9d=h36c2ea0_0
  - kernel-headers_linux-64=2.6.32=h77966d4_13
  - kiwisolver=1.3.1=py37h2527ec5_1
  - krb5=1.17.2=h926e7f8_0
  - lcms2=2.12=hddcbb42_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.35.1=hea4e1c9_2
  - libblas=3.9.0=8_openblas
  - libcblas=3.9.0=8_openblas
  - libclang=9.0.1=default_hde54327_0
  - libcurl=7.71.1=hcdd3856_8
  - libedit=3.1.20191231=he28a2e2_2
  - libev=4.33=h516909a_1
  - libffi=3.2.1=he1b5a44_1007
  - libgcc-ng=9.3.0=h2828fa1_18
  - libgfortran-ng=7.5.0=h14aa051_18
  - libgfortran4=7.5.0=h14aa051_18
  - libgomp=9.3.0=h2828fa1_18
  - libiconv=1.16=h516909a_0
  - liblapack=3.9.0=8_openblas
  - libllvm9=9.0.1=hf817b99_2
  - libnghttp2=1.43.0=h812cca2_0
  - libopenblas=0.3.12=pthreads_hb3c22a3_1
  - libpng=1.6.37=h21135ba_2
  - libssh2=1.9.0=hab1572f_5
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.3.0=h6de172a_18
  - libtiff=4.2.0=hdc55705_0
  - libuuid=2.32.1=h7f98852_1000
  - libwebp-base=1.2.0=h7f98852_0
  - libxcb=1.13=h7f98852_1003
  - libxkbcommon=0.10.0=he1b5a44_0
  - libxml2=2.9.10=hee79883_0
  - libxslt=1.1.33=h31b3aaa_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.3=h9c3ff4c_0
  - make=4.3=hd18ef5c_1
  - matplotlib=3.3.4=py37h89c1867_0
  - matplotlib-base=3.3.4=py37h0c9df89_0
  - mpi=1.0=openmpi
  - ncurses=6.2=h58526e2_4
  - nspr=4.29=h9c3ff4c_1
  - nss=3.61=hb5efdd6_0
  - numpy=1.20.1=py37haa41c4c_0
  - olefile=0.46=pyh9f0ad1d_1
  - openmpi=4.0.5=ha4a8674_4
  - openssl=1.1.1j=h7f98852_0
  - pandas=1.1.2=py37h3340039_0
  - pango=1.42.4=h7062337_4
  - pcre=8.44=he1b5a44_0
  - pcre2=10.35=h032f7d1_2
  - perl=5.26.2=h36c2ea0_1008
  - perl-xml-parser=2.44_01=pl526ha1d75be_1002
  - pillow=8.1.0=py37h4600e1f_2
  - pip=21.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pixman=0.38.0=h516909a_1003
  - pthread-stubs=0.4=h36c2ea0_1001
  - pyparsing=2.4.7=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - pypdf2=1.26.0=py_2
  - pyqt=5.12.3=py37h8685d9f_3
  - python=3.7.8=h8bdb77d_2_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
  - python_abi=3.7=1_cp37m
  - pytz=2021.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - qt=5.12.5=hd8c4c69_1
  - r-base=4.0.2=h95c6c4b_0
  - readline=8.0=he28a2e2_2
  - reportlab=3.5.60=py37h69800bb_0
  - scipy=1.5.3=py37h8911b10_0
  - sed=4.8=he412f7d_0
  - setuptools=49.6.0=py37h89c1867_3
  - six=1.15.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - sqlite=3.34.0=h74cdb3f_0
  - sysroot_linux-64=2.12=h77966d4_13
  - tk=8.6.10=h21135ba_1
  - tktable=2.10=hb7b940f_3
  - tornado=6.1=py37h5e8e339_1
  - wheel=0.36.2=pyhd3deb0d_0
  - xorg-kbproto=1.0.7=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-libice=1.0.10=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libsm=1.2.3=h84519dc_1000
  - xorg-libx11=1.6.12=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libxau=1.0.9=h7f98852_0
  - xorg-libxdmcp=1.1.3=h7f98852_0
  - xorg-libxext=1.3.4=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libxrender=0.9.10=h516909a_1002
  - xorg-renderproto=0.11.1=h14c3975_1002
  - xorg-xextproto=7.3.0=h7f98852_1002
  - xorg-xproto=7.0.31=h7f98852_1007
  - xz=5.2.5=h516909a_1
  - yaml=0.2.5=h516909a_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h516909a_1010
  - zstd=1.4.8=ha95c52a_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what can be expected for SO users to help with here. [The linked repo Issue](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/issues/22909) clearly describes this problem and the only workaround is to use an older version, but that workaround requires Python <=3.6, which conflicts with OP's Python 3.7 in the current environment.

If really only Python 3 is needed, without specifically 3.7, then create a new environment<sup>**1**</sup> with Python 3.6 and the workaround version of MEME:

```bash
conda create -n meme -c conda-forge -c bioconda python=3 bioconda/label/cf201901::meme
```

Otherwise, you need to solicit the feedstock maintainers to address the issue, i.e., [add your voice to the issue](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/issues/22909).

---

<sub>**[1]**: One might also attempt downgrading to Python 3.6 in the current environment, but mutating the Python version in an existing environment always entails changing a plethora of packages, so it won't conserve any space. Plus, Conda can solve new environment creation much faster than mutating an existing one.</sub>